# Loop through fields of two  single objects entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(orders neworders) 
{
    string modifields;
    orders oldorders = HDB.orders.Where(c => c.id_order == cmd.id_order).First();
    foreach (var field in oldorders)
    {
          if(field!= neworders.samefield)  
          {
              modifields+=nameoffield ;
         }            
    }
}
```

**Q** How can i compare a field from the new and from the old record and save the name of the field if the value is changed?

Comment: i think that neworder and oldorders are just a single objects

Answer (score 1):

An example of the Equals() method override to compare instances of the same class

```
  public override bool Equals(object anObject)
  {
     if (anObject is Order)
     {
        Order newOrder = (Order)anObject;
        if (newOrder.Name.Equals(this.Name)) //add additional comparisons as needed.  You could also use a foreach loop here as Tony shows below
        {
           return true;
        }
        foreach (var field in typeof(Order).GetFields())
        {
            if (field.GetValue(this) != field.GetValue(newOrder)) { return false; }
        }
        foreach (var property in typeof(Order).GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.GetValue(this, null) != property.GetValue(newOrder, null)) { return false; }
        }

     }
     return false;

  }
```

Here's how to call in your action:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Edit(orders neworder)  
{     
    orders oldorder = HDB.orders.Where(c => c.id_order == cmd.id_order).First();     
    if(oldorder.Equals(newOrder)
    {
       //do wome work
    }
}
```

Comment: if (newOrder.Name.Equals(this.Name)) I have over 40 fields How can i do this easier

Comment: @SilviuMarinica....you could use a foreach loop similar to Tony's post.  I'll add that to my answer

Answer (score 1):

`First()` returns a single object, so can't be iterated over.

Reading between the lines it looks like you want to iterate over all the fields on the object.  In that case you can use reflection to return a list of fields which you can then iterate over.

```
foreach (var field in oldorders.GetType().GetFields())
{
    var value = field.GetValue(oldorders);
}
```

**EDIT:** from your other comments it looks like you are wanting to compare the object against another object, in which case you are better off implementing the  `IEquatable<T>` interface.  E.g.

```
class Order : IEquatable<Order>
{
    // TODO: add properties of an Order
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Order other)
    {
        foreach (var field in typeof(Order).GetFields())
        {
            if (field.GetValue(this) != field.GetValue(other))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        foreach (var property in typeof(Order).GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.GetValue(this, null) != property.GetValue(other, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say your `orders` class doesn't implement the `IEnumerable` interface properly. In order to use `foreach` in this manner you must implement the interface and at least account for all of the methods required to support it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your oldrders variable is not Enumerable.  The First() method returns a sinlge object.  Remove the .First() and you will have an Enumerable object which the foreach loop can use